# In Mimic (about giant insects that evolved to resemble men) -- the story and/or the movie, any indications that the insects are intelligent?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, sentience, mimic

I read the story long ago and my sense was, the insects had to be fairly intelligent to blend in and come to think of it, seemed to be able to, for example, implicitly open doors and other human things.

The movie, except for the fundamental concept, is pretty different from the short story by wollheim, but it is also my sense that the mimic were not simply insects that resembled humans physically but otherwise behaved like cockroaches or whatever species they evolved from -- I think in the movie there also may have been indications that the mimics were much smarter than small cockroaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen the film but I have read and enjoyed the short story.

The story tells us very little about the man in black. However it implies he (or as it turns out "she") has a job because it tells us:

> Once in the early morning, when we would see his six-foot figure come out of the grimy dark hallway of the tenement at the end of the street and stride down toward the elevated to work – again when he came back at night.
>
> ...
>
> Where he worked I don’t know and never found out. He had money, for he was reputed to pay his rent regularly when the janitor asked for it

And:

> He would buy some groceries, maybe once a week, at Antonio’s – but only when there were no other patrons there. Antonio said once that he never talked, he just pointed at things he wanted and paid for them in bills that he pulled out of a pocket somewhere under his cloak.

So the insect must have been able to perform a job well enough to earn money for rent and groceries. That implies it is of comparable intelligence to humans, or at least more intelligent than the other primates.

Comment: Yes, that pretty much establishes it in the original story. That such details were left out of the film is disappointing and while I don't remember much about the film, the wikipedia synopsis makes the insect sound more intelligent than other insects -- they abduct humans (although ants do things like that). If these insects can do work, I wonder if they would be exploited rather than exterminated.

Comment: Kind of unlikely it had a job -- much more likely is that it took money from humans it killed. That it apparently commuted would just be sensible so as murders did not occur near where it lived. Alternatively, the "money" it used could have been mimics that its body produced, maybe made of the same material as its scales or exoskeleton. I never considered that it might actually have a job of any sort -- unless it perfectly mimicked a human, it would be discovered and indeed, it could survive on food it bought instead of eating humans -- I think I am right that it ate humans in the story.

Comment: How funny if it indeed had a job, reminds me very tangentially of the George and also Kramer episodes dealing with their work, especially the one where Kramer (implausibly) only hangs out at a company but is not an employee.  If the insect did have one, what would make sense is that it was a night watchmen or ala Bradbury, worked in a funeral home. Hard to imagine the insect attending morning meetings -- his lack of participation would cause his boss to say something to the effect, You need to contribute more.